# Implementing custom oauth-provider?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-provider

I want to implement Oauth-provider in such a way.
I have one project in which i am accessing the rest apis. Now i want to create my own oauth-provider for every api to hit.I google alot but count not found anything from which i can start my implementation.

I found google code for auth-provider but i am not been able to make it run. Code url is 
[auth-provider from google code.](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/example/oauth-provider/)

In jsp once i say that create my oauth then i want to create oauth setting from my oauth-provider. So that i can get it and send it in header to test my api.

I also download IBM code but not getting how should i start.
[IBM oauth 2.0 code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/security/library/se-oathjavapt1/index.html)

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: If you are comfortable with java then I suggest you try the spring-security-oauth2. It has fairly simple tutorial to get started with here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth